# Creating List of repeated days when using Unix Timestamp Results in extra entires

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, unix-timestamp

I got some help on here earlier about creating a list of values between two numbers where each number repeats a certain number of times. I am now trying to do it with dates. The problem I am running into is I think my dates have to be integers for list comprehension, but instead of one integer representing a day, in unix, it represents a second. So my code works fine, but it has 86,400 (seconds in a day) entries per day. Is there an easier way to handle these dates and if not what can I do to limit my results to days, not seconds.

```
from  datetime import date
import time
import datetime
now =  date.today()

LastDate = '3/24/2015'
LastDate =  int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(LastDate, "%m/%d/%Y").timetuple()))
now =  int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(now), "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple()))

Repeats = 10
ProjectDates = [x for x in range(now, LastDate+1) for y in range(Repeats)]
print ProjectDates
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

Create a `datetime` object representing today:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()   
today = datetime(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day)
```

Create another `datetime` object representing the target day:

```
lastdate = datetime(year=2015, month=3, day=24)
```

Set number of repeats:

```
repeats = 10
```

Now create a generator to generate all days in the range, stepping one day at a time (can be abstracted to an argument):

```
def generate_days(start, target):
    if start <= target:
        c = start
        t = target
        while not (c.year, c.month, c.day) == (t.year, t.month, t.day):
            yield c
            # using timedelta to step one day at a time
            # datetime + timedelta as you'd expect
            c += timedelta(days=1)
        # give out last day
        yield c
```

Finally, create you list:

```
project_dates = [x for x in generate_days(today, lastdate) for y in range(repeats)]
```

Together it looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()   
today = datetime(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day)

lastdate = datetime(year=2015, month=3, day=24)

repeats = 10

def generate_days(start, target):
    if start < target:
        c = start
        t = target
        while not (c.year, c.month, c.day)  == (t.year, t.month, t.day):
            yield c
            c += timedelta(days=1)
        yield c

project_dates = [x for x in generate_days(today, lastdate) for y in range(repeats)]

print project_dates
```

Comment: Your solution works. I modified the second to last line to be `project_dates = [datetime.strftime(x,"%m-%d-%Y") for x in generate_days(today, lastdate) for y in range(repeats)]` but that is mostly preference. thanks!

Comment: I changed some code. Make sure you have the last edit. Good luck :-)